# Make entity framework available in all projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

I have a solution with 3 class library's, one main and 2 that are referenced from the main. I installed entity framework 6 successfully from nuget and I can use it  ok in the main project. But my models etc are in this other project but when I add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

to the top of my other project I get an error and cant use : DbContext etc. When I install via nuget is that on an individual project basis?

Thanks

Comment: Right click on your solution, choose Manage Nuget Packages for soulution , see what you have installed for each projects. you need entity framework installed in each project, for this to work

Comment: You always install NuGet packages to a project. So the answer is: Yes, you have to install dependencies in each of the projects. However, only one NuGet package will be maintained for your entire solution, and that is a good thing.

Comment: If you installed via the Package Manager Console, there is a drop down at the top for you to select the Default Project the command will work with  (if not specified with `Install-Package`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage NuGet references by single project or for entire solution.
Right click on the solution, then click on "Manage NuGet packages for Solution..." to install/remove/upgrade on entire solution.

Comment: Yes, I just had to tick the box beside the other project (VS 2015). Thanks

Comment: @CerIs, then perhaps you could accept this as the correct answer if it works for you?